# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: get array

Tags: java, gwt, neo4j

*I am working on Neo4j and I am trying to fetch the detail of all user who have done their registration on specific date have have calculated the date and time along with the ids of user in order to help me in getting the detail of that specific user only. but i m facing problem in getting the detail of user with ids .. here is my code..

```
public Connection graphdbConnect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://"+"192.168.1.*" + ":7474/", "neo4j", "****");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}



public  ArrayList<DataFetech> GettingCurrentDate() {
    ArrayList<DataFetech> dataFetechs=new ArrayList<DataFetech>();
    Date dateobj = new Date();
    Calendar calobj = Calendar.getInstance();

    long oneDayInMilli=86400000;

    long currentTime= dateobj.getTime();
    System.out.println("current time"+currentTime);

    calobj.setTime(dateobj);
    calobj.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calobj.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calobj.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calobj.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    long currentDateInMilli=calobj.getTimeInMillis();

    Connection connect = null;
    String query=null;



    long startTime = currentTime;
    long endTime = currentDateInMilli;


    try {
        connect = graphdbConnect();
        Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();

        if (connect != null) {
            for(int i=1;i<=7;i++)
            {
                DataFetech dataFetech=new DataFetech();


                System.out.println(startTime+"----"+endTime);
                try {
                    query="match(n:learner) "
                            + " where "+endTime+"<=n.registrationtime<="+startTime+" "
                            + " return count(n) as total,collect(n.name) as cname";
                    System.out.println(query);

                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query.toLowerCase());

                    while(rs.next()){
                        int total = rs.getInt("total");
                        System.out.println("shalini"+total);
                        //vartika jain
                        ArrayList<String> userids= new ArrayList<>();

                        Array cname = rs.getArray("cname");

                        String[] userArray = (String[])cname.getArray();

                        for(String user: userArray) {
                        userids.add(user);
                        }
                        dataFetech.setIdslist(userids);
                        System.out.println(userids);
                        dataFetech.setTotal(total);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                startTime = endTime;
                endTime = currentDateInMilli-(oneDayInMilli*i);
                Date date=new Date(startTime);
                String dates=DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);
                dataFetech.setDateinfo(dates);
                System.out.println(dates);
                dataFetechs.add(dataFetech);
                // System.out.println("Milliseconds to Date: " + df.format(currentDate));
            };
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(connect!=null) {
            try {
                connect.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return dataFetechs;
    //return ;
}
```

**ERROR on line :- String[] tagsArray = (String[])rs.getArray("cname").getArray();**

> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: get array
>       at org.neo4j.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.getArray(AbstractResultSet.java:807)
>       at org.neo4j.jdbc.AbstractResultSet.getArray(AbstractResultSet.java:837)
>       at com.dbconnect.server.GreetingServiceImpl.GettingCurrentDate(GreetingServiceImpl.java:232)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Are you using the Bolt driver? Also which version of Neo4j are you using? The BoltResultSet from the bolt driver in version 3.0.x implements getArray().

Comment: No, i am using neo4j jdbc driver.I am using neo4j COMMUNITY EDITION
3.1.1

Comment: Jar using -neo4j-jdbc-2.3.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Just I tried the new version of the jdbc driver that I got from the official website of neo4j still its giving the same error. I am using java 1.8 is this a matter of concern?

Comment: For Neo4j 3.0.x and up, it's recommended to use the [latest JDBC driver](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc), the driver you're using is for older versions of Neo4j.

Comment: I am using the latest version of JDBC driver then also I am facing the same problem

Comment: The AbstractResultSet doesn't implement that method, but the implementing result set should. I don't see the actual type of the result set in your stack trace. Can you print out the actual ResultSet class being used? Additionally, can you show the line where you get the Connection object (you can omit the credentials, but I want to see how you get it, and what protocol you're using, the first parameter should be something like: "jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost")

Comment: @InverseFalcon Check I have added the code you have asked for and we are using jdbc drivers not bolt drivers.